# Angular Change dynamically div's visibility with ng-model

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I'm trying to change dynamically the visibility of the div with

```
ng-show="models.show"
```

the following code, was my first thoughts:

**but it's not working.**

html

```
   <div ng-init="models.show=false" ng-show="models.show"> 
        Show!
   </div>
   <button ng-click="hideshow()">Click </button>
```

javascript/angular

```
$scope.hideshow= function(){
        $scope.models.show = ($scope.model.show)?false:true;
};
```

Comment: which is it ....`models` ...or .. `model`?? You are using both

Comment: 'models', sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this

```
<div ng-show="show"> 
        Show!
</div>
<button ng-click="hideshow()">Click </button>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.show=true;
$scope.hideshow= function(){
    $scope.show=!$scope.show
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do something like this:

```
<div ng-init="show=false">
    <div ng-show="show"> 
            Show!
    </div>
    <button ng-click="!show">Click</button>
</div>
```

No Need of going back to the controller in this case.